# Mediaplayer continues to play

Tags: android, audio, path, media-player

I have a media player and everytime that this activity is called if there is a media player playing i want it to stop and the new media player start playing ... This is my audio player method

```
private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception{

mediaplayer.release();
mediaplayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaplayer.prepare();
mediaplayer.start();
```

}

I initialize the media player at the beginning of the class

```
private MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
private Handler handler = new Handler();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.songplaying);

    // Getting Our Extras From Intent
     Bundle names = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Getting Specific Data

     path = names.getString("pathkeyword");


     //Start Player
     try {
        playAudio(path);

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Everytime this is class is created it creates a new media player doesn't stop the other one and just plays both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to look into `onPause` and kill the media player then. The problem is that there is no reference to the media player once it has been made a 2nd time. As a result, you start up your activity, play the music, but when you exit (e.g. press the HOME button) the media player has not been told to stop (it runs as a separate thread). When you reopen it, it will start a new media player on a new thread, producing two sounds.

To fix this, kill the media player properly when you exit. This will properly kill the media player when you quit the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mediaplayer.isPlaying()){
        try{
            mediaplayer.stop();
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException){
            Log.d("mediaplayer","Media player was stopped in an illegal state.");
        }
    }
}
```

If you wish to continue the music whilst the activity is not in the foreground, you need to use a `Service`.

Comment: You need some way of stopping the audio. Where in your code do you do that then?

Comment: oh Thank you so much man for the explaination and stuff thanks